# Automating extraction of Windows event logs across RDP

Tags: windows, powershell

I am analysing windows event viewer logs as a part of my work and those are erased after 5 days. Across 100 machines , i am trying to automate the saving of Windows Event Viewer logs. Will powershell be able to do that ?

Comment: Yes, but there's several ways of doing it according to how your environment is set up, if WinRM is enabled on all machines etc.

Comment: You may want to consider setting up a central loghost and forward events to that host.